# servo library, understanding PWM writing.

Tags: arduino, pwm

I don't understand how multiple PWM outputs are supposed to work. Look at the pic. 
[image]

In the first(1) case we are using short signal width which would be close to motor staying still. In this case, as can be seen, short pulses follow each other, so does the code.

```
motor1.writeMicroseconds(shortWidth);
motor2.writeMicroseconds(shortWidth);
motor3.writeMicroseconds(shortWidth);
motor4.writeMicroseconds(shortWidth);
```

when motor4 ended it's output, motor1 starts it's pulse again causing non-problem consequent pulses.

In the second(2) case pulse is wider which corresponds to setting motor speed close to maximum. After motor1 finishes generating width, it's time for motor2 to generate one. But when it does, motor1's period comes to end and it has to start generate width again, but arduino is busy generating pulse of motor2.

How does PWMs work in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look directly at the code of `Servo.h` and `Servo.cpp`. But two things to help understanding:

1. The servo does not react to PWM (pulse width modulation - pulse
   duration versus cycle duration but the PDM (pulse duration
   modulation - absolute time value). This means the servo does not go
   to 0 when pulse has 0 duration, it goes to middle range (90°) when pulse
   is 1.5 ms, it goes towards minimum position (0°) when
   pulse is 1 ms and it goes to maximum position (180°) when pulse duration
   goes to 2 ms. Total cycle is always around 20 ms. To be more precise, it generally
   does not fully reach 0° and 180° and the min time is 0.5 ms and the max time
   is around 2.5 ms, but this is beyond the specification of most servos.
2. Several servos are controlled by a single timer (usually timer_1
   on Arduino). The timer is programmed when you do Servo.write(value),
   then the hardware generates the pin change at the right time.

You can try the following code:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myServo1;
Servo myServo2;
const int servo1Pin = 9;
const int servo2Pin = 10;

void setup(){
    // attach servo to pin 
    myServo1.attach(servo1Pin);
    myServo2.attach(servo2Pin);
}

void loop(){
    myServo1.write(15); //set servo to 15°
    myServo2.write(45); //set servo to 45°
    delay(1000); //wait 1 second
    myServo1.write(90); //set servo to 90°
    myServo2.write(90); //set servo to 90°
    delay(1000); //wait 1 second
    myServo1.write(165); //set servo to 165°
    myServo2.write(135); //set servo to 135°
    delay(1000); //wait 1 second
}
```

Comment: I've made a mistake writing about servo. What I deal with is basically a ESC with a brushless motor. Does it use PDM as well?

Comment: @user3081123 The ESC for a brushless motor is significantly more complex if you want efficient control. Check this short video [ESC DIY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i025lh_P-Pw)